# Block ads in WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview, adblock

I want to block ads in my WKWebView. 
I've one JSON file for rule list in which all ads domain is added but it's not woking.

Code I'm using to block ads:

```
let jsonString =
        """
[{
  "trigger": {
    "url-filter": ".*",
    "if-domain":["googleads.g.doubleclick.net","pagead.googlesyndication.com","pagead1.googlesyndication.com","pagead2.googlesyndication.com"]
  },
  "action": {
    "type": "block"
  }
}]
"""


WKContentRuleListStore.default().compileContentRuleList(forIdentifier: ruleId1, encodedContentRuleList: jsonString) { [weak self] (contentRuleList: WKContentRuleList?, error: Error?) in
                if let error = error {
                    self?.printRuleListError(error, text: "compile json string literal")
                    return
                }
                if let list = contentRuleList {
                    self?.webview.configuration.userContentController.add(list)
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: ruleId1)
                    completion?()
                }
            }
        }
```

If I use this rule then it's blocking images in webView:

```
let jsonString =
            """
    [{
      "trigger": {
        "url-filter": ".*",
        "resource-type": ["image", "style-sheet"]
      },
      "action": {
        "type": "block"
      }
    }]
    """
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let contentToBlock = """
                {
                  "trigger": {
                    "url-filter": "googleads.g.doubleclick.net*"

                  },
                  "action": {
                    "type": "block"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "trigger": {
                    "url-filter": "pagead.googlesyndication.com*"

                  },
                  "action": {
                    "type": "block"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "trigger": {
                    "url-filter": "pagead1.googlesyndication.com*"

                  },
                  "action": {
                    "type": "block"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "trigger": {
                    "url-filter": "pagead2.googlesyndication.com*"

                  },
                  "action": {
                    "type": "block"
                  }
                }
            """
```

If you add this: `googleads.g.doubleclick.net` you're requesting the specific domain

Comment: could you add me more about his usage and all?

Answer (score 0):

There is a framework on GitHub called [WKJSON](https://github.com/Ashwin-Paudel/WKJSON).

Just copy this code

```
import WKJSON

//...

    let BlockerString = """
                    {
                      "trigger": {
                        "url-filter": "googleads.g.doubleclick.net*"
    
                      },
                      "action": {
                        "type": "block"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "trigger": {
                        "url-filter": "pagead.googlesyndication.com*"
    
                      },
                      "action": {
                        "type": "block"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "trigger": {
                        "url-filter": "pagead1.googlesyndication.com*"
    
                      },
                      "action": {
                        "type": "block"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "trigger": {
                        "url-filter": "pagead2.googlesyndication.com*"
    
                      },
                      "action": {
                        "type": "block"
                      }
                    }
                """
    
    
    webView.JSONString(JSONString: BlockerString, webView: WKWebView)
```

If you want to load a JSON file, use this code

```
webView.JSONFile(filePath: "blockerList", webView: WKWebView)
```

I highly recommend that you use this JSON [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brave/brave-ios/development/Client/WebFilters/ContentBlocker/Lists/block-ads.json)

Comment: WKJson link not working. can you help me